# WSO2 Tenant authentication failed

Tags: wso2, wso2-identity-server

I can't create users in specific tenant (domain) in WSO2 identity server 5.7.0

First i create a new domain:
Using soap ```/services/TenantMgtAdminService``

```xml
<soapenv:Envelope xmlns:soapenv="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/" xmlns:ser="http://services.mgt.tenant.carbon.wso2.org" xmlns:xsd="http://beans.common.stratos.carbon.wso2.org/xsd">
   <soapenv:Header/>
   <soapenv:Body>
      <ser:addTenant>
         <!--Optional:-->
         <ser:tenantInfoBean>
            <!--Optional:-->
            <xsd:active>true</xsd:active>
            <!--Optional:-->
            <xsd:admin>admin</xsd:admin>
            <!--Optional:-->
            <xsd:adminPassword>admin</xsd:adminPassword>
            <!--Optional:-->
            <xsd:createdDate>2019-07-01T00:00:00</xsd:createdDate>
            <!--Optional:-->
            <xsd:email>admin@test.com</xsd:email>
            <!--Optional:-->
            <xsd:firstname>admin</xsd:firstname>
            <!--Optional:-->
            <xsd:lastname>user</xsd:lastname>
            <!--Optional:-->
            <xsd:originatedService>?</xsd:originatedService>
            <!--Optional:-->
            <xsd:successKey>true</xsd:successKey>
            <!--Optional:-->
            <xsd:tenantDomain>test.com</xsd:tenantDomain>
            <!--Optional:-->
            <xsd:tenantId>1</xsd:tenantId>
            <!--Optional:-->
            <xsd:usagePlan>demo</xsd:usagePlan>
         </ser:tenantInfoBean>
      </ser:addTenant>
   </soapenv:Body>
</soapenv:Envelope>
```

Now i active the previous domain:

```xml
<soapenv:Envelope xmlns:soapenv="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/" xmlns:ser="http://services.mgt.tenant.carbon.wso2.org">
   <soapenv:Header/>
   <soapenv:Body>
      <ser:activateTenant>
         <!--Optional:-->
         <ser:tenantDomain>test.com</ser:tenantDomain>
      </ser:activateTenant>
   </soapenv:Body>
</soapenv:Envelope>
```

I wish to create a users in new domains or tenant, i use curl using scim api:

```sh
curl -k --user admin@test.com:admin --data '{"schemas":[],"name":{"familyName":"John","givenName":"Doe"},"userName":"newtestuser","password":"testPwd123"}' --header "Content-Type:application/json" https://localhost:9443/wso2/scim/Users
```

My WSO2IS is using configuration for email address as the username

My log for new user :

```sh
[2019-07-13 11:23:13,380] ERROR {org.wso2.carbon.identity.scim.provider.auth.BasicAuthHandler} -  Authentication failed for the user: admin@test.com@carbon.super
```

What i doing wrong? or what i missing?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you are using email as username, the tenant's admin username also should be an email.

Hence, your curl should be as follows,

curl -k --user admin@test.com@test.com:admin --data '{"schemas":[],"name":{"familyName":"John","givenName":"Doe"},"userName":"newtestuser@abc.com","password":"testPwd123"}' --header "Content-Type:application/json" https://localhost:9443/t/test.com/scim2/Users

Here the SCIM endpoint of the tenant test.com should be: https://localhost:9443/t/test.com/scim2/Users

The username should be: newtestuser@abc.com (email as username)

Basic Authentication: admin@test.com@test.com (as this is a tenant user, we need to add the tenant domain as well.